# Is it reasonable, If we use popup mode for Single Sign On?

Tags: popup, single-sign-on

Our applications have OAuth for Google and we use popup mode. The Login page has a button for authorization via Google.

But now customers want to use a single sign-on (SSO) for authentication. As I know about SSO, we haven't used a login page app, we redirect to the login page of the SSO website. So it makes sense when we use popup mode for SSO.

We put a button keycloak (SSO) and show a popup for authorization. But it's flow is the same OAuth.

Would you show me the reasonable way to use popup mode for SSO or SSO only use redirect mode?

Comment: We're concerned here with what makes a good user experience, I think you should re-word your question to the effect or perhaps consider Stack Overflow if you're concerned about implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Good day, here You have a process of typical SSO.

I think SSO in this circumstances should use only redirect mode,without pop-up because:

1. Less user interaction.
2. Easier, cheaper implementation

[image]

Comment: How is this answer to the question ? I read it more than thrice. I guess discrete answer with connection to question would make it helpful even of others, than the one who asked.